# Polygons being clipped during pst-solides3d projections

Tags: pstricks, pst-solides3d

I'm having trouble doing something that seems very simple, so I'm hoping that I've made a naive mistake.

I'm attempting to project several polygons onto a plane using the \psProjection feature in pst-solides3d.

My polygons project nicely as long as the plane's normal is facing down the x axis. As the plane tilts back (rotating about the y), at first things are fine. However, once the plane tilts back enough my polygon starts getting clipped and disappears from the top down. By the time the plane is tilted totally back, with normal pointing up the z axis, the image has completely disappeared from the plane.

Am I misunderstanding something about the way these projections are supposed to work?

My ultimate goal is to have 3 planes like this one, each with an image, and have them intersect to illustrate an algorithm I'm working on. If pstricks isn't the ideal way to do this, I'd appreciate other suggestions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,5)
    \psset{viewpoint=30 0 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=60,lightsrc=viewpoint}
    \psset{solidmemory}
    % Set normal in plane to [0.25 0 1 0] to reproduce
    \psSolid[object=plan,name=pp1,definition=equation,args={[1 0 0 0] 90}]
    \psset{plan=pp1}
\psProjection[object=polygone,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,plan=pp1,args=-1 -0.5 1 -0.5 1 0.5 -1 0.5]
\psProjection[object=polygone,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,plan=pp1,args=-1 0.5 0 1.5 1 0.5]
\psProjection[object=polygone,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,plan=pp1,args=-0.25 -0.5 0.25 -0.5 0.25 0.25 -0.25 0.25]
\composeSolid
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Plane normal down x axis, image correct]

[image: Plane normal at 0.75 0 1, image starting to get clipped]

[image: Plane normal at 0.25 0 1, image clipped even more]

Comment: the roof of the object is behind the plane. The reason why you cannot see it.

Comment: @Herbert: Sorry, could you clarify a bit? The house is entirely drawn in 2D coordinates in the plane (the polygone lines specify only 2d coords), so I don't understand how the roof can be "behind the plane" - everything should live in the plane and "go along for the ride"

Comment: your projection plane is _before_ your roof, the  reason why the roof is projected onto the backside of the plane and not seen. Use an x value for the plane which is smaller than the one of the roof, eg `[-1.25 0 1 0]` and you'll see it.

Comment: @Herbert: Sorry, again I don't understand. The entire house is specified in 2D coordinates on the plane, so it has no depth - only a width and a height. Changing the normal of the plane to [-1.25 0 1 0] changes the angle of the plane. What I want to do is draw the house on the xy plane, e.g. on the plane with normal [0 0 1 0], not on the plane with normal [-1.25 0 1 0].

Answer (score 1):

The credit all goes to Manuel Luque. Here I quote his email:

> The projection polygon, circle etc.. is clipped into a rectangle
>   corresponding to the base of the projection plane. It is in
>   `pst-solides.pro` line 11237 and following lines.
>
> ```
> /proj-pst-polygone {    proj-action (none) eqstring not {
>       l@pl@n plangetrange aload pop
>       setyrange setxrange
>       newpath
>          xmin ymin l@pl@n pointplan smoveto
>          xmin ymax l@pl@n pointplan slineto
>          xmax ymax l@pl@n pointplan slineto
>          xmax ymin l@pl@n pointplan slineto
>          xmin ymin l@pl@n pointplan slineto
>      planprojpst projpath
>       clip % <-------
>       solidlinewidth setlinewidth
>       linestyle
>       linecolor
>       proj-definition length 0 eq {
>          [proj-args]
>       } {
>          proj-args
>       } ifelse
>       proj-definition cvx exec polygone_
>       planprojpst projectionsifacevisible projpath    } if    /projname where {
>       pop
>       proj-definition length 0 eq {
>          [proj-args]
>       } {
>          proj-args
>       } ifelse
>       proj-definition cvx exec projname cvlit exch def
>       /projname where pop /projname undef    } if } def
> ```
>
> We must therefore enlarge the base.